# How to makes the return type of an override single-expression function to Unit?

Tags: function, kotlin, return-type

How do you override a function returning `void` or `Unit`, with a [single-expression function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#single-expression-functions) whose expression returns some non-`Unit` type? For example:

```
interface Base {
  fun overrideMe(): Unit
}

class Derived: Base {
  override fun overrideMe() = runAsync { }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After thinking, I found the best way is using `let` at the top-level for the **override** single-expression function to return a `Unit`, and then no need *else-clause* at all, for example:

```
class Derived : Base {
    //                         v--- uses `let` here
    override fun overrideMe()=let{if (Math.random() < 0.5) runAsync { /*TODO*/ }}  

}
```

**OR** using let in if expression, for example:

```
class Derived : Base {
   // use let to return Unit explicitly , but I think T.let{Unit} is more clearly
   // and the Unit is optional you can do it as T.let{} simply    ---v
   override fun overrideMe() = if (Math.random() < 0.5) runAsync { }.let { Unit } 
                               else Unit
}
```

**OR** makes the `Unit` at the last statement as below:

```
class Derived : Base {
    //                                         return Unit explicitly ---v
    override fun overrideMe() = if (Math.random() < 0.5){ runAsync { }; Unit }
                                else Unit
}
```

Comment: This does not work. Note how `foo()` does not override anything in your example.

Comment: @breandan hi, please give a minimal example.

Comment: Sure, please see the example above.

Comment: @breandan Hi, how about it now?

Comment: I guess so. But with the amount of extra characters required, wouldn't I just be better of writing `override fun overrideMe() { runAsync() }` (updated code to the *minimal* example).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149520/discussion-between-breandan-and-holi-java).

Answer (score 1):

You can make `Unit` of any expression by using one of the functions in the `kotlin-stdlib`:

- `override fun foo() = someExpression.let { }`
- `override fun foo() = Unit.apply { someExpression }`

Or write your own extension `fun Any.toUnit(): Unit = ...` in any way and use it afterwards.

Comment: Seems hack-y. If these are the only options, I would rather just write `override fun foo() { someExpression }`. Although I wish it were possible to write `override fun foo(): Unit = someExpression` and just have the result of evaluating `someExpression` ignored if the return type is `Unit`.